# how can i hide TRibbon pages?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl, ribbon

i'm using delphi 2009's TRibbon component.  certain pages are not relevant depending on the application state.  how can i hide a TRibbon page?

RibbonPage1.Visible:=false doesn't really hide the page...

is this maybe not allowed by the spec from microsoft?

thank you for you help!
mp

Comment: Just a side note -- you really can't do this because it violates the specification.  Ribbons are not supposed to be dynamic or to change in anyway.

Comment: oh...i didn't know that.  if you put that in as an answer i'd like to make it as the answer.  thank you Nick!

Comment: But the other way around is allowed: depending on the current state of the application some extra ribbon tabs may be shown. For instance, select an image in Word 2010 and see the extra tab that is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can hide the individual ribbon pages, but you can hide or disable the individual [RibbonGroups](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Ribbon_TRibbonGroup.html) on the each page.

```
RibbonGroup1.Enabled := false; 
RibbonGroup2.Visible := false;
```

Microsoft Office disables any groups which are not relevant to the current state.  Have a look at these articles from the documentation for more help.

- [Creating an Application that Uses Ribbon Controls](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/win32_ribboncontrols_xml.html)
- [Adding Commands to the Ribbon](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/win32_ribboncontrols2_xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this presently. It is the Tabs (not the Pages) that need to support visibility and they simply do not.

If you try to manipulate the Tabs themselves you will find the code is very dependent on maintaining the linkage between the pages and the tabs to the point of destroying your pages. I don't think there is a good workaround.

Register it as a bug in [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx). Support for "Context" aware tabs/pages is definitely something that should be supported. I imagine quite a few others would vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this is the only hide/show thing that is handled correctly by that piece of borland crap.

MainRibbon.RemoveTab('TabName');

I am now searching how to hide group and individual actions. Visible = false is not ok, try to resize your form smaller and in the collapsed state all is still there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, try this: RibbonPage1.Free;

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Delphi XE6)

```
MainRibbon.Tabs[RibbonPage.Index].Visible := FALSE;
```

Then you can make it visible again by

```
MainRibbon.Tabs[RibbonPage.Index].Visible := TRUE;
```